# How do I properly transform entire canvas in fabric.js / change fabric's origin?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to set fabric up so the origin is bottom left instead of top left. Currently I'm using `setViewportTransform` and it transforms everything as I want, except for the selection box. (doesn't seem to get the transformation) I made a fiddle & you can see how if you rotate the rectangle, the selection box rotates the wrong way.

So my question is, how do I set fabric.js' origin to the bottom left?

http://jsfiddle.net/39up3jcm/105/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution I found was to:

1. Change the view by adding `transform: scaleY(-1)` to the canvas CSS
2. Change the inputs by redefining `fabric.Canvas.prototype.getPointer` but replace `pointer.y = pointer.y - this._offset.top` with `pointer.y = bounds.height - pointer.y + this._offset.top`

** Fabric version 1.7.20